# Quarkus: Flyway cannot connect to postgres Dev Services

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I'd like to run integration tests against a fresh postresql container containing a database created by Flyway.

`build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
dependencies {
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client")
  // flyway does not work with the reactive driver right now, a workaround with a classic driver
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway:2.6.1.Final")
}
```

`application.yml`

```yaml
application:
  flyway:
    migrate: true
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: postgresql
    devservices:
      enabled: true
      image-name: "postgres:14.1-alpine"
"%dev":
  quarkus:
    datasource:
      jdbc: false
      devservices:
        enabled: false
      username: ${db.user}
      password: ${db.pwd}
      reactive:
        url: postgresql://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.name}
    flyway:
      migrate-at-start: true
```

`QUARKUS_PROFILE=test ./gradlew --info test-integration`

At first it looks good: the Dev Services start the specified postgres container:

```
2022-03-14 13:54:19,527 INFO  [ .1-alpine]] (build-29) Creating container for image: postgres:14.1-alpine
2022-03-14 13:54:19,557 INFO  [ .1-alpine]] (build-29) Starting container with ID: d1ab***snip***4c96a
2022-03-14 13:54:19,770 INFO  [ .1-alpine]] (build-29) Container postgres:14.1-alpine is starting: d1ab***snip***4c96a
2022-03-14 13:54:20,759 INFO  [ .1-alpine]] (build-29) Container postgres:14.1-alpine started in PT1.248185S
```

but then Flyway fails...

```
    Caused by:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    ...
        Caused by:
        org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:51445/default?loggerLevel=OFF
            at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForUrl(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:55)
```

The good thing is the container comes up with a random port (51445) and it's somehow passed to flyway. I'm not sure why Flyway uses the reactive URL. If I understand it right, it succeeds connecting to the container but the database (`standard`) is not there?

Quarkus Version: 2.6.3.Final

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus does yet currently support Flyway + Reactive Datasources. See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10716) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution: the following bean runs when your app starts ("observes StartupEvent") and configures Flyway to use the JDBC driver for the migration:

```kotlin
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway

@ApplicationScoped
class MigrationServiceConfiguration {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "application.flyway.migrate")
    lateinit var runMigration: String

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url")
    lateinit var datasourceJdbcUrl: String

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
    lateinit var datasourceUsername: String

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
    lateinit var datasourcePassword: String

    fun runFlywayMigration(@Observes event: StartupEvent) {

        if ("true" == runMigration) {
            val flyway =
                Flyway.configure().dataSource(datasourceJdbcUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword).load()
            flyway.migrate()
        }
    }
}
```

*Something* sets `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` env variable to the correct value including the randomly assigned port Postgres is listening at. The `datasourceUsername`, `datasourcePassword` are not set in my `application.yml`.

The prerequisite is that you have both the JDBC and reactive dependencies (see my `build.gradle.kts`)

Comment: Still a problem - the `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` secret sauce still works.